# Conditional auth_request in Nginx

Tags: nginx, auth-request, njs

I need to add conditional authorization to a redirection in Nginx, only when one defined url parameter is received (t in this case). And the value of this parameter has to be passed to the authentication server as a Bearer token in the Authorization header.

I have tried using ideas taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40431767/2249460), but I can't get it to work.

Let me explain what I want to achieve with an example.

My server receive: /sec/foo  proxy to http://localhost:3001/foo

but if it receives: /sec/foo?t=valid_token, I need proxy to http://localhost:3001/foo?t=valid_token after previously validating the token with service http://validate:8080, which can expect as a Bearer header (also works if the token is received as parameter).

```
set $val "";
location /sec/ {
    # idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69961396/2249460
    if ($arg_t != "") {
        set $val $arg_t;
        rewrite ^ /__sec__$uri last;
    }
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
}
location /__sec__ {  
    internal;
  # I tried to save token value and set header en both location. Didnt work
  # set $val $arg_t;
  # proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $arg_t";
    rewrite ^/__sec2__(?<realurl>/.*)$ $realurl break;
    auth_request /_test_auth;
    error_page 401 403 500 =401 /error/401;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
}
# Auth location shared with other locations
location /_test_auth {
  internal;
  set $val_auth $http_authorization;
  if ($val != '') {
    set $val_auth "Bearer $val";
  }
  proxy_pass http://validate:8080;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header Authorization $val_auth;
  proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control Vary Set-Cookie;
  proxy_cache cache_zone;
  proxy_cache_key $val_auth;
  proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
}
```

I tried to do the same using the njs module, and I also obtained negative results.

```
location /sec/ {
  auth_request /_js_auth;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
}
location /_js_auth {
  internal;
# I need to set the Authorization header, but I dont have the token
  proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $arg_t";
  js_content auth.main;
}
location /_test_auth as defined above
```

auth.js content:

```
function main(r) {
    if (r.args.t !== undefined) {
        r.subrequest('/_test_auth', function (reply){
            // I need pass the arg value as a header or set in a variable to use in proxy_set_header
            r.return(reply.status);
        });
    }
    r.return(200);
}

export default { main };
```

Any suggestions?